# Constructiing and modifying trees with the Data.Tree module

Tags: haskell, tree, containers, binary-search-tree

I would like to use trees to store lists of words with Haskell. I would like to uses a generic NTree (n-ary) for my purpose and I thought that the [Data.Tree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Tree.html) module from the [container](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1) package could be the good solution.

My problem is I don't know how to deal with this module, its API is very different from Data.Map for example.

**Do you know what are the functions to insert an element, import datas from a list, test presence of elements, etc ?**

**Is my module choice right? Is their another module suitable ?**

Comment: This is not a *search tree*, it is a "simple" tree...

Comment: Is their another package providing a generic search tree?

Comment: Why don't you just use `Data.Map` and not worry about the actual tree implementation?

Comment: I could use `Data.Map` but I don't want to lookup a value according to a key, but simply test if a value is member of the Tree. The `member` function from `Data.Map` test if a key is present. I want to test if a value is present.

Comment: So `Data.Set` then? (Or equivalently a `Data.Map` where the values are stored in the key fields, and the mapped values are `()`.)

Answer (score 1):

As per @leftroundabout, you're probably looking for [`Data.Set`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.4/containers-0.6.2.1/Data-Set.html#t:Set).  This is a tree-based implementation of sets supporting `insert`, testing for `member`ship, and conversion `fromList`.

As noted in the documentation, the implementation uses size balanced binary trees, so they aren't general n-ary trees.  If you really want to use n-ary trees, you're probably going to have to write your own implementation from scratch, perhaps using `Data.Tree` as a starting point.